# Getting (Estimated) Time Offset of the Errors Reported by ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, timestamp, report, offset

I'm using ffmpeg to check for errors in video files, but while it reports tons of issues it doesn't tell me where exactly the error happens in the file. It just dumps some crazy long hex numbers (0x7fa…) which doesn't tell me anything. Is there a way to make it report some timestamps, or at least estimated timestamps, or byte-offsets into the stream? I tried the `-debug_ts` flag, but nothing changed in the output.

```
$ ffmpeg -debug_ts -v error -i a_broken_file.mp4 -f null -
[h264 @ 0x7fa513023400] Reference 4 >= 4
[h264 @ 0x7fa513023400] error while decoding MB 15 34, bytestream 1304
[h264 @ 0x7fa513023400] Frame num change from 36 to 72
[h264 @ 0x7fa513023400] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7fa513023400] Invalid NAL unit size (-1989965076 > 2668).
[h264 @ 0x7fa513023400] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[aac @ 0x7fa513007200] Prediction is not allowed in AAC-LC.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x7fa513007200] channel element 3.8 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x7fa513007200] channel element 3.11 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x7fa513007200] channel element 2.10 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x7fa513007200] Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 0x7fa513007200] get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid argument
[aac @ 0x7fa513007200] Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 0x7fa513007200] get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid argument
[aac @ 0x7fa513007200] channel element 3.1 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x7fa513007200] Reserved bit set.
…
```

Or perhaps I could extract this information from the hex numbers there (I haven't found a single information about what this number stands for)?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct use of the **-debug_ts** option (in Windows 7 64-bit):

```
ffmpeg.exe -debug_ts -re -copyts -i file.mp3 -f null out.null >result.txt 2>&1
```

All timestamps in the input media file will be written out to a text file (which can then be parsed for errors).

My intention here is only to show the proper use of **-debug_ts** not to demonstrate any parsing techniques, all of which are necessarily much more complex than the trivial task of merely writing out the timestamps to a file.